# determine the country name from received IP address

Tags: c, linux, ip

I want to know if there is a function or code in C which allow to know the country code or name from the received IP address. 
thanks

Comment: Take a look --> http://www.nirsoft.net/countryip/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using [libgeoip](https://github.com/maxmind/geoip-api-c/blob/master/README.md). You can find an [example](https://github.com/maxmind/geoip-api-c/blob/master/test/test-geoip.c) in the test subdirectory. It basically works like:

```
GeoIP *gi = GeoIP_open(path_to_database, flags);
const char *country_code = GeoIP_country_code_by_addr(gi, "127.0.0.1");
```